# How to create a machine learning model for a fire detection system?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, weka

Recently I start with machine learning. I want to create a machine learning model for a real-time fire detection system. Input data is environmental features and output data is fire possibility. When Time=0, we set the fire. Just for example:

```
    Time  Temperature   CO   CO2 ... ...  Fire_Possibility
    -20   20            **   **           Low
    -15   21            **   **           Low
    -10   19            **   **           Low
    -5    20            **   **           Low
     0    22            **   **           Med
     5    25            **   **           Med
    10    27            **   **           High
    15    31            **   **           High
    ... ...
    ... ...
```

I'm trying to train a neural network with Weka, so for every moment, I calculate the rate of change and the relative value for each attribute and then train the model, like this:

```
    Time  Tem_Rate_of_change     Tem_Relative_value   CO   CO2 ... ...  Fire_Possibility
    -20   0                      0                    **   **           Low
    -15   1                      1                    **   **           Low
    -10   -2                     -1                   **   **           Low
    -5    1                      0                    **   **           Low
     0    2                      2                    **   **           Med
     5    3                      5                    **   **           Med
    10    2                      7                    **   **           High
    15    4                      11                   **   **           High
    ... ...
    ... ...
```

But I couldn't get a model with high accuracy. I think it is better to make detection with all the values in the past instead of using values in one moment. 
I don't know if there exist machine learning model which can be trained with values in a range of time in the past. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

For your case, i think what you need to do are at least 3 things:

- Feature engineering: carefully design a set of features inclusing selecting relevant features from your data, creating derivate features, discarding non relevant features(for example i think your current time ist not a relevant feature, or is there a mathematical relationship/correlation between  time and fire possibility?). You can get help from feature selection algorithms and packages for this.
- Perform "Machine learning diagnosis" and plot learning curves: this will help you identify if you have underfitting, overfitting and depending on your results define your following action(theres guideline depending on the case)
- Perform error analysis: analyze some missclassification examples and verify if theres a pattern or common behavior in them, categoryze them and think in actions that could help to perform a better classification.

And another advise: instead of trying a 3 class classficiation ,try a binary classificaton and get a real number between 0 and 1 representing the probability of fire.